# Add inputs and outputs to a transaction signed with sighash SINGLE | ANYONECANPAY

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, bip174-psbt, sighash

I created a transaction with one input and one output, and signed it using sighash `SINGLE | ANYONECANPAY`.

Can I add further inputs and outputs with another wallet using bitcoin-cli?